# Angular 6 - Injector.get<service>(service as Type<service>) error: Type 'Type' is not Generic

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4, angular6, ng-bootstrap

Angular 6
Typescript 2.7
I am getting Renderer2 service to use in my component.spec.ts. See below code-

```
renderer2 = fixture.componentRef.injector.get<Renderer2>(Renderer2 as Type<
  Renderer2
>);
```

my code compiles but i see this error: "Type 'Type' is not Generic" in my terminal.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume [this](https://angular.io/api/core/Type) is the `Type` you mean to use?  It's generic, so maybe you are getting the wrong `Type` somehow.  If you jump to the definition of `Type` (e.g., in Visual Studio Code, hold Control and click on `Type`), what do you see?

Comment: Hi @MattMcCutchen, i have checked the definition. Its the same interface Type extends Function. What else could have gone wrong?

Comment: Does it have something to do with the version of Typescript being used?

Comment: Can you publish a repository that reproduces the problem so I can investigate?  That will be much more efficient than me trying to give you individual things to check remotely.

Comment: I could setup a repository but that takes time. This issue needs to be fixed urgently (by today), i can execute your suggestions , remotely. Can you think of any other reasons as to why this error?

Comment: I would look at what build tool you are running that shows the error and try to ensure that VS Code is using the same settings so that hopefully the "go to definition" will point out the culprit.  If that doesn't work, I would try to minimize the example by deleting code.  Just standard troubleshooting procedures; I don't have a specific likely cause in mind.